# "sudo chmod 0 /" deployed as script to remote MACs via Landesk

Tags: macos, bash, script, sudo

This probably will not make a lot of sense.
We have users that have left the company and have not returned their macs.
We are using Landesk as main managing platform, however the MAC managing part is kind of limited.
I need a way to remotely deploy a script which will run as admin.
The main challenge is to save this command `sudo chmod 0 /` which I believe it to be very efficient in disabling the the machine . It works very well through ARD but I need to deploy it as script to remote macs that are not on the same network but have the Landesk client installed and have it run hidden.
Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Please could you confirm the company has tried contacting these individuals directly and at least issued a legal request to return the company's property? You are proposing to remotely harm a device and make its data inaccessible. Depending on your legal jurisdiction, and the situation's fine detail, this could lead to "bad things" for your role in the action.

Comment: Hi Graham, Thank you for bringing that up. I apologise for not mentioning that from the start. This is for users that have persistently failed to return the machine despite HR chasing them and so on. This is a way for us to prevent loss of sensitive information when company machines are "lost".

Comment: Doesn't LANDesk have the ability to lock down a compromised workstation?  Why wouldn't you use that?  But to @GrahamMiln point, rather than disable it which would cause "bad things to happen (angry user turns MBP into Frisbee, for instance), it may be better to consult an attorney.  You may have better luck with a perceived threat of a larceny charge for non-returned hardware.

Comment: Hi Allan, Yes This works for Windows PCs but not for Macs.

Comment: Do you wish to remotely disable machines?  I might have a better way that involves a launchd boot service.  Results in a kernel panic, every time.  Machine willnbe unbootable until the launchd stops running the service at boot,  Are you able to create new launchd boot services with your remote control software.

Comment: Hi Francis, Thank you for your reply. Yes, I want to disable the Mac machines. Wouldn't "kernel panic" require System Integrity to be disabled?